# Confuse about the meaning of this sentence with プリプリ/puripuri?

Tags: grammar, meaning, japanese-to-english, video-games

[Screenshot](https://preview.redd.it/kmnfkvu95la91.png?width=1106&format=png&auto=webp&s=5e159be37c9a11768585d0663d781f764051ba03)

**I'm reading a VN ,and encounter this sentence in a H scene . The "puripuri" part make me confuse because it stand after 感触が and before と俺 .
(Is it an adjective for "俺のペニス" ? Or it describe the feeling of MC like 膣内の感触がプリプリ ?)

So appreciates if anyone can help me understand this sentence's correct meaning**

**むっちりとしたフォルムと肉厚な膣内の感触がプリプリと俺のペニスを締め付けて離さない。​**

(my guess but not sure : "The feeling from her chubby body form and her thick vagina is (puripuri ?) ,keep tightening around my penis and doesn't let it go" )

Comment: No プリプリと modifies 締め付けて離さない

Answer (score 2):

Just remember and apply the basic rule. と after an onomatopoeia is always an adverbifying suffix, and it never forms an adjective. You should look for the next **verb**, which is 締め付ける in this sentence. It's the verb that corresponds to プリプリと.